# How to create a dynamic range variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write to cells in a certain range inside a column.

```
Range("B7:B(noOfTests)") = "Not Tested"
```

What am I missing? Is there a better practice for what it's trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternate.

```
Range("B7").resize(noOfTests, 1) = "Not Tested"
```

Answer (score 5):

You need:

```
Range("B7:B" & noOfTests) = "Not Tested"
```

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on @Rory 's answer, or as to why your code doesn't work:

---

**The double quotes <kbd>"</kbd>  symbolize a String literal in VBA** *(and almost any other programming language)*.

The way a `Range` object works, is that you specify 1, or optionally 2 cells. Where Cell 1 is the starting cell *(and ending cell if not specified)* and Cell 2 is the ending cell, defining your selected range.

There are multiple ways of passing  the arguments to a range, the most common is however to use the above-mentioned string literal. eg. `Range("B7:B12")` *< note the quotes inside brackets*

**What you're however trying to do, is to dereference a variable's value inside a string literal. This is achieve in VBA via the ampersand <kbd>&</kbd> expression.**

This what you're trying to do (if interpret could read a pseudocode)

```
Range("B7:B"<insert row value>) = "Not Tested"
```

What you're however doing instead is literally inputting your variable as part of your string, so:

```
Range("B7:BnoOfTests") = "Not Tested"
```

Obviously the interpeter is confused. BnoOfTests is not a common Cell referencing format and it doesn't know what to make of it. What you need to do is dereference your variable into a value as I hinted above, so the correct solution is:

```
Range("B7:B" & noOfTests) = "Not Tested"
```

---

Other good practice to avoid the string referencing confusion is to refer to the two cells that define your range. Much like I literally described above:

> The way a Range object works, is that you specify 1, or optionally 2
>   cells. Where Cell 1 is the starting cell (and ending cell if not
>   specified) and Cell 2 is the ending cell, defining your selected range

So to make sure you don't mess it up, you can use the following definition:

```
Range(Cells(7, "B"), Cells(noOfTests, "B")) = "Not Tested"
```

**In my humble opinion, this is actually clearer transcription and furthermore, it is a lot less error prone!**